# php using foreach on an object will only run once

Tags: php, object, foreach

I have a snippet of code that will over a DatePeriod object run some code. In some situations I need to run this foreach on the DatePeriod a couple times.

```
foreach($objects as $object){
   foreach($period as $date){
     //do stuff
   }
}
```

on my development server this runs fine, when I switch to production. It will only run the first time. Every subsequent attempt will skip over the $period foreach.

I can fix this issue by unsetting the $period object and initializing it, but I rather not do that if I can avoid it.

Does anyone know why my code is behaving the way it does only on my production server?

Thanks.

Comment: Are the PHP version / OS of the dev server and the production server the same?

Comment: Does a `reset($period);` after the period foreach fix the issue?

Comment: @TimothyChoi
[production: PHP Version 5.3.2-1 on ubuntu]
[development: PHP Version 5.4.7 on windows 7 (xampp)]

Comment: @popthestack nope, that was the first thing i tried.

Comment: The last comment in the [Documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateperiod.php) mentions bugs in some versions of PHP when you do multiple `foreach` loops on the same DatePeriod.

Comment: @barmar i'm not sure that is relevant to my issue because in your link, the period foreach still runs, it just does not behave in the expected manner. in my issue the foreach over the dateperiod is skipped entirely, but thank you for spending time trying to help me :)

Comment: Either way, 5.3.2 has a bug that prevents it from working correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your help everyone, but I found the issue digging through php patch notes.

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=52668

i'll have to see about updating to a newer version of php on my production server.